# Inner regularity of Gaussian measure

Tags: measure-theory

I am a bit stuck while showing the property of the Gaussian measure that it is inner regular, that is to show that

$\gamma(A)=\sup\{\gamma(K)\vert K\subseteq A , K \space\text{compact}   \}$ where $\gamma$ is the Gaussian measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Is there any equivalent formulation of inner regularity? I think that it is not so easy to check with the definition above...

Comment: mhmmm... and why is your last claim true? I think it is not trivial...

Comment: Oh, I was trying to show something stronger, i.e. that $\inf\{\gamma(A\setminus K)\mid \ldots\}=0$... that is easier. And true. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If $X=\bigcup_n X_n$, where $X_n$ are all closed (resp. compact) and of finite measure $\mu$, and $\frac {\textrm{d}\nu}{\textrm{d}\mu}$ exists is bounded on each $X_n$, then if $\mu$ is inner regular with respect to closed (resp. compact) sets, then so is $\nu$.

To see this, just notice that $\nu$ restricted to each $X_n$ is inner regular, and look at the unions of (increasingly better) approximations of $A\cap X_n$.

Comment: sorry, but I dont see how this would help me... so many new notations...

Comment: @tubmaster $\frac {\textrm{d}\nu}{\textrm{d}\mu}$ is the standard notation for the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\nu$ with respect to $\mu$. I don't see any other piece of notation beyond elementary set theory. What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I did not know the definition of the Gaussian measure, so I misread it in the first reading: i missed the minus sign in the exponent. There is actually a much easier argument in this case.

Note that by definition, the measure of any set with respect to the Gaussian measure is no greater than its measure with respect to the Lebesgue measure. Since the Lebesgue measure is regular, so is the Gaussian measure.

Comment: Thanks, sounds good. But do you mean by "the measure of a set wrt Gaussian/Lebesgue measure" the integral form as above or just the Gaussian/Lebesgue measure of the set?

Comment: @tubmaster: I don't really understand what you are saying. What integral form above? When I say the measure of a set I mean the measure of a set.

Comment: ok but then I really do not see your last argument: Gaussian meausre no greater that lebesgue measure of any set $\rightarrow$ inner regularity of Gaussian measure

Comment: @tubmaster: Do you know that the Lebesgue measure is inner regular?

Comment: yes I know that

Comment: @tubmaster: For sets of finite measure, inner regularity is the same as saying that for any $\varepsilon$ and $A$, we can find $K\subseteq A$ such that $A\setminus K$ has measure smaller than $\varepsilon$. If the Lebesgue measure of $A\setminus K$ is small, then so is the Gaussian measure. If $A$ has infinite Gaussian measure, then it also has infinite Lebesgue measure, so...

Comment: how should $A$ have infinite Gaussian measure? It is a probability measure... isn't it`?

Comment: @tubmaster: I have neglected the fact that you could have a set of infinite Lebesgue measure but finite Gaussian measure. But that is not really an obstacle in this case, because any set of infinite Lebesgue measure can be approximated (in Gauss measure) by a bounded (hence finite Lebesgue measure) set.

Comment: I'm not so sure about this argument.  It's not generally true that if $\mu \le \nu$ and $\nu$ is inner regular then so is $\mu$.  For instance, on $\omega_1$, let $\nu$ be counting measure and $\mu$ be Dieudonne measure.  Maybe you can salvage it in this case by knowing that $\nu$ is $\sigma$-finite but it needs more work.

Comment: @NateEldredge: I agree. The issue is what I wrote in the previous comment, that you could have a small set in the smaller measure which is large in the larger one. This is not, however, an issue if the bigger measure is $\sigma$-finite, because then you can just apply Radon-Nikodym theorem, and note that if you have $f\in L^1(\nu)$, then $f$ can be approximated (in $L^1$) by a function of finite support (specifically, a restriction of $f$ to a smaller set), which reduces to the finite-finite case.